# Custom module undefined functions

Tags: function, module, include, drupal-7, undefined

I am developing a custom module for my employer. The **my_module.module** fill got too big and unmanageable so I decided to separate related code into separate **.inc** files.

I then included those files in the following code:

```
function my_module_init(){
    module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'questionnaire_nodetypes');
    module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'questionnaire_config');
    module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'email_friends');
}
```

My code continued to work for a while but I suddenly got a **undefined function** error for a function that was definitely present in **questionnaire_config.inc**. Other similar errors soon followed for other confirmed and existing function in the other included .inc files.

It was suggested to me to run the **update.php** script but this did not fix the problem. In fact, I got more **undefined function** errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to put those lines in a hook, just dump them straight into the top of the module file (I've been doing it for years and it's never caused an issue).

`hook_init()` doesn't get called for cached pages, so it's conceivable your files aren't being included when another (non-cached) part of the system is relying on the existence of those functions.